# Moving view but keeping imageview in fixed position

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm moving a `UIView` up with a swipe, but I want the imageView within the UIView to stay in its position.  I got this working by placing my imageView under a separate UIView ( I needed to include a label under the imageview) by doing `[self.view insertSubview:self.imageViewHolder aboveSubview:self.panedView];`.  The problem now is that when i swipe down over the imageView, my view that I swiped up won't come back down unless I swipe around the imageView.  This is because the `UIGestureRecognizer` is associated with the view under the imageView.  Any simple ways around this?

Gesture recognizer code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeUpRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleUpSwipe:)];

[self.panedView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpRec];
[self.imageViewHolder addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpRec];
```

Comment: have you tried adding a gesture recognizer to your imageview (in addition to the recognizer on the view?

Comment: I tried doing that but the swipe up behaves oddly and becomes glitchy.

Comment: have you implemented any of these delegate methods? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I added in my gesture recognition code.  I don't think any of those delegate methods are necessary since I have only one Swipe Up recognizer that i'm using for both views.

Comment: create a separate instance of swipeDownRec and add that to the image view

Comment: I adjusted my code quite a bit, but in the end i still have two views that appear simultaneously that need to respond to the same gesture.  I created a separate instance of swipeDownRec and called it secondarySwipeDownRec.  I added this to the second view, but it doesn't respond.  swipeDownRec works fine.